# A key part in the expectation of geometric distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, expected-value

I'm learning the proof of the expectation for a geometric random variable. The proof is as follows:

[image]

I just cannot understand the parts where I place two red boxes.

Why can we use differentiation here to get $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty }k(1-p)^{k-1}$?

Is there any theorem which I can follow?

Comment: The first red box: They got $p$ out of the sum because $p$ is not indexed in the sum. It does not change the value of the sum whether you include it or not. For the second red box: If you notice, $k(1 - p)^{k - 1}$ is the derivative of $(1 - p)^k$ which is a geometric sequence.

Comment: @ZouhairElYaagoubi thanks, I have understood about it.

Answer (score 1):

> I just cannot understand the parts where I place two red boxes.

Expectation describes the average value of a random variable.

$\begin{align*}
E(X) = \begin{cases} \sum_{x} x \, p_X(x) & X \text{ is
a discrete RV}\\
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x \, f_X(x)\, dx & X \text{ is a continuous RV}
\end{cases},
\end{align*}$

If you go from the *third step to the second* in your linked image then it will be more clear. I think it is just more creative use of the [differential operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_operator). Think of the operator as a function that just maps  denote a function which maps functions into their derivatives.